# Continuity and real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Consider the functions $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$, $g(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$, and $h(x)=\frac{|x|}{x}$, all defined on $ℝ\setminus\{0\}$, what do we set $f(0)$ to be for $f$ to be continuous on $ℝ$? Do the same for $g$ and $h$.

I know for a function to continuous in a point, it has to fulfill:
$$∀ε>0 \; ∃δ>0: \|f(x)-f(a)\|<ε, \; ∀x \in A \text{ with } \|x-a\|<δ $$

But of course, looking at $f(x)$ it is not defined at $0$? So it doesn't matter what I set $f(0)$ to be, because $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ will never be defined at $0$. Is my logic correct? Do the same logic applies for all three functions?

Answer (score 2):

No. The question is telling you to do is, essentially, extend the definition of $f,g,h$. For instance, choose a value $\alpha$ such that
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
1/x^2 , & x \ne 0 \\
\alpha, & x = 0 \end{cases}
$$
is a continuous function. They already know that the functions aren't defined at zero; what they want to know is that, if the functions ***were*** defined at zero, what value they'd have to take on in order to ensure continuity.

Comment: Can you give me a hint on how to find f(0) then? Do I just find the limit at f(0)?

Comment: That is essentially one way to tackle questions like these: if
$$
\lim_{x \to x_0^+} f(x) = \lim_{x \to x_0^-} f(x) = \alpha
$$
then you want $f(x_0)=\alpha$ for continuity. Honestly, I feel like the question as stated to you is a tad misleading, since $f$ "blows up" at $0$ and $h$ has a "jump discontinuity" at $0$, so you cannot assign (finite, real) values for either function and preserve continuity. I guess they want you to prove that no such value can be assigned, in those cases.